# Database API and Security

Tags: database

I'm working on a controller that queries a table based on the value in a route parameter

Example route path:

```
path: '/path/{parameter}'
```

Controller:

```
  public function myFunction($parameter) {
    $connection = \Drupal::database();
    $query = $connection->select('my_custom_table', 'mct');
    $query->condition('mct.col', $parameter, '=');
    ...
    $result = $query->execute();
    $records = $result->fetchAll();
```

Is there any sanitization that should occur in this circumstance or does the database API take care of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For input, saving to the DB, Database API takes care of it, automatically prevents SQL injection **when using [dynamic query](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries)**. Since your code is using dynamic query, you're all good.

If you were to use **[static query](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/static-queries)** you have to make sure you use [placeholders](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/static-queries#placeholders) as the docs mention.

For output, to prevent XSS, you'll want to use a template file, and print your value via Twig. Which auto escapes everything by default. If you don't use Twig, then you need to use the [appropriate API function](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/security/writing-secure-code-for-drupal-8#s-api-functions).